# Django Rest Framework - Front End Choices

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to figure out how DRF meshes with front ends. I've been looking for tutorials that use the typical template views as normally done with django but i cant find any. I CAN find lots of tutorials and documentation with DRF using REACT JS and Angular JS as a front-end.

Could someone please explain why this is the case and why there are no tutorials using the typical html templates? is it a matter of convenience, efficiency, lack of options, or something else?

All insight and advice is appreciated.

Comment: DRF provides REST apis, and SPA's usually consumes REST api's. React is used to build SPA. There are no templates because usually a rest api returns json or xml objects, so no template is needed.

Comment: i would have thought that django would be able to display the html for the django project itself and then when any other device like an iphone or android would ping it, thats would get back the JSON. So it sounds like learning angular or react is my only option then, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django does, but DRF is Django Rest Framework. What you are saying in your comment is what is called content negotiation. This means that the server reads the headers Accept and depending on it gives the response in html, xml, json, plain text, yaml or whatever

I dont see the point about react in this history. If you want to build webpages in Python, you can use Django, Flask, any other framework or plain Pyhton.

If for some reason you want to use DRF and build a rest api, you will need something to show that data to your users. It could be a standard site using ajax calls, an SPA done with React, Angular, Vue... or a mobile app.

As you can see React is not the only option.

Comment: got it. Thank you!